# Need UI selector like "dateRangeInput" for numeric fields in R Shiny application

Tags: r, date, shiny, numeric

There is a UI element "dateRangeInput" for the R Shiny application that looks like

```
  dateRangeInput(
    "daterange3", 
    "Date range:",
    start  = "2001-01-01",
    end    = "2010-12-31",
    min    = "2001-01-01",
    max    = "2012-12-21",
    format = "mm/dd/yy",
    separator = " - ")
```

I need the same kind of UI element but for numeric fields with start, end, min, and max values initiated, one title, and "to" text between start and end elements. For example, set numeric metric "Age":

```
  numericRangeInput(
    "age", 
    "Age range:",
    start  = "10",
    end    = "30",
    min    = "0",
    max    = "150",
    separator = "to")
```

Any help will be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sliderInput` ?

```
shiny::sliderInput('num', 'Select num', 0, 100, c(10,20))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak as always! I found a "numericRangeInput" from "shinyWidgets"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found by myself

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$br(),
  numericRangeInput(
    inputId = "noui1", 
    label = "Numeric Range Input:",
    value = c(100, 400)),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res1 <- renderPrint(input$noui1)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```